# Django global setting parameters affected after overriden?

Tags: django

In django/conf/global_settings.py

```
DEBUG=False
```

In my project settings.py

```
DEBUG=True
```

but when i access the DEBUG from global_settings.py like

```
from django.conf import settings
print settings.DEBUG   //True
```

its printing True not False, why ?

and my second question is that

if Django has to provide DEBUG=True for each project setting file(myproj/setting.py)  , then why cannot it make DEBUG=True in global_settings.py rather than DEBUG=False ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[1] Your global settings are overwritten by your `settings.py` file as detailed in the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#default-settings).

From the docs:

> Here’s the algorithm Django uses in compiling settings:
>
> - Load settings from global_settings.py.
> - Load settings from the specified settings file, overriding the global settings as necessary.

Also when you think you are importing your global settings with `from django.conf import settings` you aren't actually accessing the module but an object (why you can't run from `django.conf.settings import DEBUG`) and that object is the output of the algorithm above.

[2] The reason you have to specify `DEBUG=True` for each project (rather than have it in the `global_settings.py` file) is for security reasons.

The debug parameter displays a lot of personal information to the project which is useful for debugging in development but never should be accessible in production. So Django requires that a user explicity specifies to enable `DEBUG`.